# cannot add Android library to my project

Tags: android, eclipse

I tried to add Android library to my project  , in the first time I do this I see green arrow and when I open the project properties again I see 
[image]

what is the problem ?

Comment: copy the library to your workspace (folder where your android project is). now try referencing the library project. not sure if it helps try moving your workspace out of C drive.

Comment: Try cleaning the project properly also the l;ibrary project and see if that helps.

Comment: you have to paste your library in same path of your project. then it will work for you

Comment: thanks @abhishesh. I used your trick and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use English Character in your project and folder path names.

Good Luck :)

Answer (score 2):

Open the library as anAndroid project and then add the project.

Answer (score 1):

Say for example your eclipse workspace is in E drive and imported library project is in C drive means, copy that project(import library project) to that E drive and then import into your workspace.Then refer that library in your project.

Answer (score 1):

i was face the same problem. i think easy solution is at first create a folder on your hard disk and there you just copy your project and library project. then in eclipse add your library project and from properties make as library and then add your main project and try to same approach to add library  as you mention before.then your library will add in your project

Answer (score 0):

if you're trying to add a .jar library into your project you can try do that

- Add the **.jar file** to **libs folder** on root of your project  ( YourProject/libs )
- if the **.jar file** has a **.so file** add the **.so** to **libs/armeabi**
- refresh the project in Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

The X appearing against the referenced library project also appears if the library project has a build error.  This happened to me after updating ADT at some point.  There was something in the newer version that must have performed extra validation, in my case it was a few strings in my French resource files that weren't defined.  I updated these and the X disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem. I have windows 8.1

It is impossible that the project and libraries physically lay on different disks

My project lay on a disk **C**. Libraries lay on the **D** disk

When I transferred everything to **one disk** everything earned
I hope to somebody will help